# How is data consistency guaranteed between PostgreSQL substatements of a top statement?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I'm still unable to figure out how SQL statements execute in parallel without messing each other's work. I understand the ACID principle in general, but I'm struggling to understand it on particular cases. For example, in the snippet below, could the value of `bar.max_count` not reflect the actual maximum value of `count` in table `foo` when the `UPDATE` is being executed? (for example, if someone updates or inserts new rows in table `foo` between the `WITH` statement and the `UPDATE` statement).

```
WITH 
  bar AS (
   SELECT id, MAX(count) AS max_count
   FROM foo
   GROUP BY id
  )
UPDATE mytable 
SET count = bar.max_count
FROM bar
WHERE mytable.id = bar.id
```

In other words: would this statement "block" other concurrent statements that attempt to write in table `foo`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could happen that concurrent statements write to `foo` before you update `mytable`. However, as long as the concurrent statements don't also read from `mytable`, everything is fine, because then your transaction can be considered to *logically* predate these other transactions – it is as if though your transaction ran first.

But if one of those concurrent transactions also read a value from `mytable`, the result need no longer be consistent, if that information went into modifying `foo`, because then you can no longer logically order the transactions. This is known as a transaction *anomaly*, because it could never happen if the transactions were executed one after the other (serialized).

You get this kind of anomaly if you operate on the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, which offers a low level of transaction isolation.

To avoid such anomalies, you would have to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, where you are guaranteed to always have a serializable outcome. But there is a performance cost associated with `SERIALIZABLE`, and anomalies are resolved by terminating one of the involved transactions with a *serialization error*.

The alternative is pessimistic locking, but that would lead to excessive locking in your case.

Comment: I will give your post several reads. It seems that, after all, it's not easy stuff. Thank you!